# Tie sublime text with the pdf viewer

Tags: windows-10, sublime-text-3, window-manager

I'm using Sublime Text 3 for LaTeX, and it works great. My only concern is that it uses an external PDF viewer (SumatraPDF), so I have 2 windows to work with. If these were the only windows I needed, there would be no problems. Unfortunately, I also would like to use other things on my PC, so:

- To switch to a different window, I need to use two Alt-Tabs, which is annoying.
- If I want to restore the side-by-side view of sublime and Sumatra, I need an even more annoying combination of Alt-Tabs.

Is there a way to "tie" them together, so that they appear/disappear simultaneously? Alternatively, is there a way to use an internal PDF viewer in sublime text? I found https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Non%20Text%20Files, but it simply doesn't work.

My OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX has an inbuilt IDE with combined pdf viewer but many users preferer to pick & choose either another editor with imbedded viewer or use separates for different reasons.

Unfortunately there are no simple means in windows to glue two separate apps panes as one split pane (even SumatraPDF itself has to use separate windows per drag and drop instance etc.
In theory & practice it should be possible to write an application that allows SumatraPDF to be imbedded in another as a plug-in (that's how many cloned copies work) However it is not a shortfall thus not an issue as outside SumatraPDFs remit.

I have only seen one such recent product and like many in that class it tends to have issues with different title bars and tabs. You may be able to get a better mix than my attempt. (as I support SumatraPDF , I have to say this is unsupported usage and entirely up to you to do own support.) It is [free for private use](http://www.systemgoods.com/#taskspace) and v5 2017 has not been updated as much as the commercial v7 2021 offering http://www.systemgoods.com/#tasklayout

[image]

other recent possibilities such as https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windowresizer.html can be found here https://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/sortdate/shell_enhancements.html